# Python Tkinter Text Alignment

Tags: python, tkinter, label, text-alignment, toplevel

I am using Tkinter with Python2 to create a new window by clicking on the button. In this new window I want to Display text. Now I have Troubles with the alignment, is it possible to align it to the left? It is always centered and neither anchor=LEFT nor sticky="NSEW" help.

```
import tkinter as tki

btn3 = tki.Button(self.root, text="HELP", command=self.help, fg="black", bg="white", font=("Courier",22))
btn3.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NSEW" )

def help(self):
    self.text = """ Hello. 
                    You can find help here to the following subjects:
                        - getting started
                        - installation
                        - FAQ."""  
    self.top = tki.Toplevel()
    self.top.title("Help")
    self.label1 = tki.Label(self.top, text = self.text, height = 0, width=80, fg="black", bg="white", font=("Courier",18))
    self.label1.pack()
```

Comment: are you wanting to align the button or text box?

Comment: When you use `anchor=LEFT` it should give you an error something like `_tkinter.TclError: bad anchor LEFT: must be n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w, nw, or center`. Which means, you should carefully read thrown errors.

Comment: I want to align the text. So that it Looks exactly as i put it above.

Comment: I tried anchor =n as well and it doesn't work.

Comment: yes, i know. but it says global name 'w' is not defined. So it is more a problem using aelf.label1.pack(anchor=w).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `anchor = n` you need to put `anchor = "n"` i.e. with the n in quotes. You're getting the global name is not defined error because of this. 
Alternatively, use `anchor = tki.N`. Because you used `import tkinter as tki` you must prefix tkinter variables with `tki.` in order for python to know what you're referring to. However, I think you might want to try `justify=tki.LEFT` also if that doesn't work.

Comment: Also, even if `LEFT` was a valid value for the `anchor` argument, you would need to write it as `tki.LEFT` because of the way you imported `tkinter`. If you did `from tkinter import *` then you wouldn't have to prefix things. However that is considered bad practice because then tkinter's names may confict with names you define and lead to name hiding problems.